# Using Javascript to create a URL that opens a request in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

Does anyone know how to generate a URL (lets say in Chrome only for now) that'd open Postman with a **new request / collection (with one request)**?

I know of this URL that imports the specified collection in Postman from Chrome:

```
https://www.getpostman.com/collections/<collection-id>
```

And I see that there is a [Run in Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/run_button) button but that seems to require a preexisting collection.

I have information about a request in my front-end webapp - I want to bundle the request information into some format that can then be sent to Postman. Any ideas?

If it helps, the context; I am displaying HTTP logs which include request bodies - I thought it'd be really cool if I could replicate the requests in Postman when needed for debugging...